# Most pythonic way to assign and access a nullable object

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I was coding on a project and at one moment I did the following code:

```
my_var = function(param)
my_var = my_var[key] if my_var else None
```

This code is working but I'm searching a better way to do it, in one line if possible.

Do you have any idea ?

In C# they is something called "Safe navigation operators" and you could have something looking like this I think:

```
my_var = function(param)?.[key]
```

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Can you share code for `function`?

Comment: Share the minimal workable code please.

Comment: It's a nullable object so function can return an object like {'key': {'second_key': 1}, ...} or directly None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of Python, as of Oct 2018, do not support optionals.

For more details, see [PEP505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/).

Comment: So none-aware operators are planned for python 3.8 ? So early 2019 according to PEP569 ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If function always returns a dictionary, you could do the following:

```
my_var = function(param).get(key, None)
```